# Login via PayPal

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I have found this example :

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/log-in-with-paypal-access.html

Does anyone know where can I exactly find the API for this? 
I can't find such information how to integrate Login-via-paypal on any paypal pages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its Paypal Access. Try this links to know about paypal access and to integrate Paypal Access in your site.
https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/paypal-access
https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/attributes
https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/getting-to-know-paypal-access